# PackageManager.checkSignatures not working on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-package-managers

I use PackageManager.checkSignatures to check whether a paid "unlocker" app is installed. While this works fine on KitKat (on a Galaxy S4), the call to checkSignatures below returns a code of -3 on Lollipop (v5.0.1). Does my code need to be revised for Lollipop?

```
final PackageManager pkgMgr = context.getPackageManager();
final int sigMatch =
        pkgMgr.checkSignatures(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                "com.myname1.myname2.myappunlocker");
```

Comment: Are you sure that the signatures do indeed match? -3 is ` SIGNATURE_NO_MATCH`.

Comment: if (sigMatch == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) returns false

Comment: Just to be clear, com.myname1.myname2.myappunlocker is installed, but my check for PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH now fails (whereas it passed on Android 4.4.2)

Comment: My point is: are you sure that the app that is running your code shown actually does match `com.myname1.myname2.myappunlocker`? For example, are you testing a debug build of the app, which is usually signed with a different signing key?

Comment: Yes I'm sure - I'm using the exact same apk that I had installed on KitKat (on the same phone)

Comment: You might check their signature hashes, using [my `SignatureUtils` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/security/src/com/commonsware/cwac/security/SignatureUtils.java) and see what comes out.

Comment: When I test the app in debug mode (AndroidStudio) I never used to get a problem with the signature match on Android 4.4.2, but now (on 5.0.1) the behaviour has changed. Does this mean that this sort of functionality can't be tested using Android Studio on Android 5.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

> When I test the app in debug mode (AndroidStudio) I never used to get a problem with the signature match on Android 4.4.2, but now (on 5.0.1) the behaviour has changed.

While I have not used `checkSignatures()` much, that behavior would stun me. The only thing that I can think of is if they had some security bug where debug builds always returned `true` from `checkSignatures()`. Otherwise, an app signed with a debug signing key should never match the signature of another app signed with a production signing key.

I know for certain that Android would report different signing keys at runtime via `PackageManager` for the different builds, as I did a *lot* of experimentation around that, as part of my work with `SignatureUtils`.

> Does this mean that this sort of functionality can't be tested using Android Studio on Android 5.0.1?

It means that you should be testing this functionality using the same signing key for both apps. Whether that is the debug key or the release key is up to you.